# MySQL where if statement

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm currently working on an API using `node.js` and `node-mysql`.

I start off by grabbing all the parameters that the client sends over like this:

```
  var userId = req.query.userId;
  var carType = req.query.carType;
  var hasOwnership = req.query.hasOwnership; (optional parameter)
```

What I would like to do is make a statement so that if the client sends the `hasOwnership` parameter with the request, my statement will return all the cars that belong to him with the specific car type. Similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_type=? AND owner_id=?, [carType, userId];
```

Otherwise it will just return the all the cars that match the car type:

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_type=?, [carType];
```

Is it possible to accomplish something like this in a single query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? When you have 2 query, the database make 2 different plan to execute them efficiently. If you combine them in a single query, it **may** that database can't plan to execute it efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can phrase the query as something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM car
WHERE (? is null or car_type = ?) AND
      (? is null or owner_id = ?);
```

Note that this version takes each parameter twice, unless you use named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty quick solution would be to use an if then else.

if hasOwnership has value the use query #1 else use query #2